# Unable to set correct file paths in RStudio

Tags: r, directory

Using the code below lead me to a path that's not working ('C:/Users/md21/Dropbox/UBx/TB-SPEED/Modelling/O3SAM/TBSsam/dataSAM_notTB.csv'), whereas I guess my issue would be fixed if I set this location ('C:/Users/md21/Dropbox/UBx/TB-SPEED/Modelling/O3SAM/TBSsam/data**/**SAM_notTB.csv')

It seems simple to fix, but I cannot figure it out (I'm new to R) - see image.

Please, help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vJ31.png)

Comment: You're not concatenating the filename correctly when you read the file in. In says it in the error message that you're looking for a file that does not exist. There is no forward slash after `../data..`

Comment: It'd probably be easier to use a paste inside your `fread` after you set `ffn` or you could concatenate the two lines and go for `fread(paste(gh('data'),fn,sep='/'))`

Comment: Your suggestion fread(paste(gh('data'),fn,sep='/')) fixed the issue. Thank you so much!!